# Asctec Pelican rotating in reverse direction when speed above 32.7 deg/s?

Tags: control, ros, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:

After solving some issues with controlling our Astec Pelican via asctec_mav_framework we updated the firmware of the HL board and until now it seemed to work just fine.

But recently we discovered another annoying issue and we have no expanation for it. It turns out that when we start sending angular velocity commands the UAV starts rotating over the Z axis (until here everything works as expected); but when we increase the angular speed over 32.7 deg/s it starts rotating in the opposite direction.

So far we've tried this sending these commands with the asctec_mav_framework utility called "ctrl_test" and using a dummy node that publish messages to /fcu/control. The behavior is the same in both cases.

Anyone has experienced this before, or have a clue about where to start looking for a solution?

Thank you in advance. Best regards,
Adrián

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244881/asctec-pelican-rotating-in-reverse-direction-when-speed-above-32.7-deg/s?/) by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used these platforms myself, but `32.7` sounds like the upper limit for a signed, integer math 16-bit variable (`-32768` to `32767`, shifted 3 sign. digits (`/ 1e3`) -> `-32.768` to `32.767`). Overflow would then result in what you are describing. Perhaps a known issue / upper limit?

Btw, just noticed this: you mention `deg/s`. Are you sure that is the correct unit? ROS standardised on radians and radians/sec. The msg docs for [asctec_hl_comm/mav_ctrl](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/asctec_hl_comm/html/msg/mav_ctrl.html) fi also explicitly state everything is in SI units.

---

Edit: ah, apparently `ctrl_test` accepts `deg/s` units to be used for this ([here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/asctec_mav_framework/blob/5d271d989d05c98d4bcd6fdf98e16f8228c3bd07/asctec_hl_interface/src/ctrl_test.cpp#L45)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on 2016-10-10**:
hi @gvdhoorn, thanks for your response. You hit the nail in the head. I've taken a look to the insights of the SDK of our UAV and although input units are in deg/s they are internally converted to millideg/s. As the value is stored as short... well, you were right! Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-11**:
Thanks for reporting back. It'd be very nice if you could report this to the relevant issue tracker. I don't know which one that would be, but this seems like something that other users might/will run into and is rather confusing.